# Get first day of given month idiomatically

Tags: kotlin, date

I have a compose view that is given a month and year. I want to find the first weekday of the given month/year combo in the idiomatic Kotlin way. This is what I have so far:

```kotlin
fun CalendarMonthView(
    month: Month = LocalDate.now().month,
    year: Int = LocalDate.now().year
) {

// ...
    val weekDayNames = DateFormatSymbols.getInstance().weekdays
    val firstWeekdayOfMonth = //type annotation in IntelliJ: (Calendar .. Calendar?)
        Calendar.getInstance().also {
            it.set(Calendar.DATE, 1)
            it.set(Calendar.MONTH, month.value)
            it.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
            it.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
            // does not evaluate to a string?
            weekDayNames[it.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)]
    }
// ...
}
```

Is there an idiomatic way to do this instead of something like:

```kotlin
val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 1)
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month.value)
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
val firstDay = weekDayNames[cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)] // type annotation: String
```

Comment: Is that a `java.util.LocalDate` you have? I don't know Kotlin, but can give you a really simple Java answer.

Comment: Yes, I'm developing on the JVM for this particular project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like:

```kotlin
val month = LocalDate.now().month
val year = LocalDate.now().year
val dayOfWeek = LocalDate.of(year, month, 1).dayOfWeek
println(dayOfWeek.name) // prints "FRIDAY" for April 2022
```

[Try it yourself](https://pl.kotl.in/nGLCA4ESI)

Comment: Alternatively `LocalDate.now().withDayOfMonth(1).dayOfWeek`.

Comment: Yeah but in the question, the function takes month and year as parameters and doesn't use current month always.

Comment: I ended up doing this based on this answer:
`val firstWeekdayOfMonth = LocalDate.of(year, month, 1).dayOfWeek.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.getDefault())`

Comment: Marked as API 26+ required. I have it enabled down to 23 in my project. Any solution for API below 26?